# What is the extra CPI due to mispredicted branches with the 2-bit predictor?

Tags: architecture, cpu-architecture

In the textbook "Computer Organization and Design 5th", page 366
Problem 4.15.3

[image]

The answer:

[image]

I wonder why the stall cycles are 3?

There are five pipeline(IF, ID, EX, MEM, WB) stages in a data path.

The problem says that the branch outcomes are determined in the EX stage.

I think it should look like this:

```
IF ID EX MEM WB
   nop
      nop
         IF ID EX  MEM
```

The stall cycles are 2, not 3.

Can somebody provides some suggestions?

Comment: It says the outcome of the branch is determined at EX stage, What about the branch target address, isn't it determined at the MEM stage?

Comment: so it’s the hidden fact that the stall cycles should be 3?

Comment: I think so, waiting for someone else to jump in and correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[Isuru H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7002215/isuru-h) is right in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325860/what-is-the-extra-cpi-due-to-mispredicted-branches-with-the-2-bit-predictor#comment83659812_48325860).

This is the data path of the pipeline as found on page 289 of the quoted book

[image: Data path with the inter-stage registers, showing that the PC is updated in the MEM stage]

As outlined on page 287 the PC is updated in the IF or MEM stages

> ■ The selection of the next value of the PC, choosing between the incremented
>   PC and the branch address **from the MEM stage**

<sup><sub>Emphasis mine</sub></sup>

A key point to understand why the PC is updated in the MEM stage while the branch executes in the EX stage is this hint on page 289

> The PC can be thought of as a pipeline register: one that feeds the IF stage of the pipeline.

This not only and obviously means that the PC is updated only on the rising/falling edge of the clock but that the PC is presented with a new value constantly.

It can be thought as

```
 write enable --
                |
 New            |
 value  .-------v-----.   Current value
-----> | Current value | --------->
        '-------------'
             PC
```

just like any [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

Let's call the branch B, the instruction on the *wrong* path W1, W2, W3, ... and the ones on the right path R1, R2, R3, ...

When the branch is executing the pipeline diagram is this

```
IF ID EX MEM WB
W2 W1 B
```

During the EX stage of B, the PC is presented with the address of W3

```
W3   .--.  W2
--> | W2 | -->
     '--'
```

because this is what is computed by the adder in the IF stage.
When a clock arrives, the branch writes its output into the EX/MEM register, including the new PC value and the PC is updated with W3.
Now the PC is presented with the address of R1

```
R1   .--.  W3
--> | W3 | -->
     '--'
```

but a *new clock* is needed to latch-in this value, thus it is only when B exists the MEM stage that the PC is correctly set.

This is multi-cycle pipeline diagram

```
IF ID EX MEM WB

B

W1 B

W2 W1 B           computing the branch outcome

W3 W2 W1 B        presenting the branch outcome to the PC

R1 W3 W2 W1  B    updated the branch outcome
```

**Note** that the delay of a branch is outlined at the beginning of chapter 4.8 (Page 316).